# How can I display upper case value in capital case In Angular toolTip?

Tags: html, angular, tooltip, primeng

My HTML:-

```
<i [class]="item.icon" [pTooltip]="item.item" tooltipPosition="bottom" ></i>
```

The value inside item.item is 'ATTACHMENT' I can not modify that from ts file
Can I do something within HTML to change the case to capital:- Attachment for
showing the tooltip?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `titlecase` pipe

```
[pTooltip]="item.item | titlecase"
```

Comment: But I want it in capital case or title case  for eg: Attachment

Comment: Ah, misread, updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using titlecase pipe we can achieve this.

```
[pTooltip]="item.item | titlecase"
```